# What is the best book for the following mentioned courses?Internet resources too please.

Tags: self-learning, education, book-recommendation, big-list

1.Motivation:Learning physics and computer science and of course the enchantment of maths itself.

2.Background:A little bit of algebra,Trigonometry utmost basics and basic geometry

3.Why it is interesting and why it should be answered? Honestly it would be of great help to anyone wishing to learn mathematics but are unable to find resources.

**1.Algebra I**

**2.Geometry**

**3.Algebra II**

**4.Trigonometry**

**5.Pre-Calculus**

**6.Calculus I(differential)**

**7.Calculus II(integral)**

**8.Statistics**

**9.Calculus 3(multivariable)**

**10.Calculus(applied)**

**11.Advanced calculus I & II**

**12.History of mathematics**

**13.Linear algebra**

**14.Abstract algebra**

**15.Number theory**

**16.Set theory**

**17.Logic**

**18.Differential equations**

**19.Introduction to analysis**

**20.Real analysis I & II**

**21.Complex analysis I & II**

**22.Differential geometry**

**23.Modern algebra**

**24.Combinatorics**

**25.Chaos Theory**

Comment: Please dont take this down.This is very important for anybody trying to learn mayhs.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution.But i need books for algebra geometry too

Comment: The scope of this question is too broad. If you need help to learn pre-calculus, it doesn't make sense to ask what books are recommended for learning differential geometry.

Comment: i AM LEARNING PRE-CALCULUS AS A STEPPING STONE TO ADVANCED MATHEMATICS

Comment: I hope this question could be split into 2.Calculus and its foremath.Calculus and its aftemath.

Comment: Is openstax relaible and enough for learning?

Comment: Do you have any goals for which you particularly want to study? Also your background is very unclear. A "little bit" could mean anything for anyone. Try to be more precise. Which chapters you have completed upto what depth etc. Pre calculus(I'm assuming you need to learn this) -> Multi variable calculus and complex analysis is a long way, and in my opinion you needn't worry about those now.

Comment: Thank you.My goal is learning physics and C.sc.My background is algebra 1 ,non-euclidian geometry,and just began trigonometry(only ratios and identities.

Comment: Oh, this is quite new. I don't think this is quite enough to be answer but.... I recently finished reading both Tao's Analysis I and II, as well as Rudin's POMA. Both books have their virtues, but Tao's is notably extremely well written and accessible. While Rudin includes a few more results than Tao, Tao's book is by no means deficient, and is even even superior by many criteria.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can find some books: [Structured math learning(how to learn maths step by step?) and resources for all the courses mainly books](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3685236/structured-math-learninghow-to-learn-maths-step-by-step-and-resources-for-all/3685258#3685258)

I will add some books:

Combinatorics and graph theory, by J. Harris

Set Theory: A First Course, by D. W. Cunningham

Differential Geometry: Connections, Curvature, and Characteristic Classes, by L. W. Tu

An introduction to Manifolds, by L. W. Tu

Mathematics and its history, by J. Stillwell

Elementary and Intermediate Algebra for College Students, by A. R. Angel

Geometry: Euclid and Beyond, by R. Hartshorne

Introduction to Geometry, by H. Coxeter

Comment: Actually  was the one who asked that question.

Comment: THank you very much

Comment: Could you please recommend for algebra 1 & ii and geometry

Comment: Higher Algebra by Hall and Knight, you may find it nice:)